# When running "sudo cleos wallet keys" I can't see the keys but with "cleos wallet keys", I can see them

Tags: cleos, wallet, keys, public-key

I've built the source I'm not using docker. I'm on ubuntu 16.04.
eos version is 1.4.3

when running

```
sudo cleos wallet keys
```

I can't see the keys but with

```
cleos wallet keys
```

I can see them.

How come?

Answer (score 1):

Guess you have `make install` with your local host